# Exists $\theta$ such that $ \cos\theta + i\sin\theta \leq 0?? $

Tags: complex-numbers

Exists $\theta$ such that
$$
\cos\theta + i\sin\theta \leq 0??
$$
For example. If I say that a number is greater than zero, then this is necessarily a number is it real?

Comment: The answer is yes. For example $\theta=\pi$

Comment: For example. If I say that a number is greater than zero, then this is necessarily a number is it real?

Answer (score 3):

The set of complex numbers is not ordered. As @TymaGaidash has mentioned, though, if you let $\theta = k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then you can compare $\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$ with zero (that is because the resulting number is real). The answer is given by $\theta = \pi + 2k\pi$.

Comment: For example. If I say that a number is greater than zero, then this is necessarily a number is it real?

Comment: @Andrémash As I have mentioned, the set of complex numbers is not ordered. However if you let the imaginary part to be zero, then you obtain a real number which can be compared to zero. The only possibilities where $\sin(\theta) = 0$ are given by $\theta = k\pi$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now it remains the question: when $\sin(\theta) = 0$ and $\cos(\theta)  \leq 0$?

Comment: Thank you very much